# Ubuntu there is a program to write iso on usb key and not make file system readonly?

Tags: usb, filesystem

I like burn my ubuntu iso on pendrive, and after that modifiy some folder or file but the file system is readonly. There is some tools like rufus for linux that not make filesystem read-only?

thanks

Comment: Modify the ISO before you put it on the USB:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd).  Specifically, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a "persistence" file, since it allows filesystem changes to be 'persistent'.  For details on setting it see [this How-to Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), or the Ubuntu wiki [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

In short, the easiest way will be to use the mkusb software: currently, that is only found in a PPA, so you'll need to do the following commands:

```
# Ensure the Universe repository is availible
sudo add-apt-repository universe
# Add the PPA
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt update
# Install the software
sudo apt install mkusb
```

That should get you to where you need to be.